# How can I make an element in Javafx not overlap with another when resizing the window?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

I am making a simple UI app on Java. I have a Listview and a progressbar underneath it. When you first run the application the UI is fine but when I resize the window the listview expands the way it should but gets masked by progressbar which stays fixed at its original point at the top and stretches out at the bottom.

Is there a way to make it so that the listview and progressbar scale up / down in proportion when the window is being resized?

I tried adding a container in between the two elements and set it to always grow vertically but it did not work either.

**main.fxml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.learning.javaui.Controller">
    <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <MenuItem fx:id="quitMenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Quit" />
        </Menu>
    </MenuBar>
    <AnchorPane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.3322884012539185" layoutX="77.0" layoutY="79.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                </padding>
                <GridPane layoutX="20.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="189.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="NEVER" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="-Infinity" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                    <TextField fx:id="nameField" prefHeight="25.0" promptText="Enter Name" GridPane.halignment="LEFT" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                    <Button fx:id="saveButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" />
                </GridPane>
                <ListView fx:id="names" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="43.0" prefHeight="330.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="40.0" />
            <ProgressBar prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="160.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="530.0" />
            </AnchorPane>
            <TabPane fx:id="userPanel" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
        </SplitPane>
    </AnchorPane>
</VBox>
```

**Screenshots:**

When app is run initially:
[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdVKx.png)

When I resize the window the elements overlap:
[Elements after window is resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdZFP.png)

Comment: Don’t hard-code all the layout positions. Use layout panes that respond to resizing the way you want it to respond (`AnchorPane` basically does no layout, especially if you specify width, height, and layout position for everything.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `AnchorPane.topAnchor="530.0"` in:

```
<ProgressBar prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="160.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="25.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="530.0" />
```

Comment: This worked! I can't believe it was such a small thing. I'm still learning though, thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

As James stated, `AnchorPane` is not recommended in this situation. I personally like to use `VBox` and `HBox` mainly in my layouts. They are very useful when nodes need to be stacked or side by side. I would use `GridPane`, if and only if, nodes needed to be stacked and side by side. Example code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.learning.javaui.Controller">
    <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <MenuItem fx:id="quitMenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Quit" />
        </Menu>
    </MenuBar>
     <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.3322884012539185" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity">
         <children>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" spacing="20.0">
               <children>
                       <TextField fx:id="nameField" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="100.0" promptText="Enter Name">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="20.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
                       <Button fx:id="saveButton" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
               </children>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" top="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </HBox>
                <ListView fx:id="names" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </ListView>
            <ProgressBar progress="0.0">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="2.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </ProgressBar>
         </children>
      </VBox>
         <TabPane fx:id="userPanel" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
     </SplitPane>
</VBox>
```

Comment: I still need to learn all the different layouts and when to use them. Thanks for the code! It will really help me in learning JavaFX